# Put button on layout bottom always

Tags: android

I have the button on the bottom on a RelativeLayout but on the page there are editTexts and when those are active the keyboard pops up and the button doesn't stay on the bottom it moves to above the keyboard. This button is for sending a finished filled in form so I can't have the button moving above the keyboard when it's activated.

This is the layout right now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ind_survey_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdfasdfds group"
                android:textColor="@color/mediumBlue"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ind_survey_anonymous_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleX="0.8"
                    android:scaleY="0.8"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_x" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ind_survey_anonymous"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/anonymous"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ind_survey_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/D5dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/D20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/D5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/mediumGray" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reclycer_view_survey_questions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/lightGray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:text="@string/send_survey"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make sure the button doesn't move when the keyboard is active?

Comment: did you add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"` in manifest?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no, this is in a fragment, what does that do?

Comment: Its root activity in manifest section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of this:

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

To avoid your Views to be adjusted as per the keyboard moment.

Add this line within your Activity Tag in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the root layout into scrollview and relative layout as the immediate child